# Ruby on Rails creation of record with nested forms and join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nested-forms, join

I am trying to implement the creation of a record with a many-to-many relationship (between surveys and questions) captured in a join table.  I want the user to be able to create a Survey an it's contained questions in a single form, but the questions do not appear.

[EDIT: After the changes by RAJ, only one question displays, and they are not saved into the database.]

[EDIT: Rails version 4.2.0, ruby version 2.2.1p85, for what it's worth]

[EDIT: Added "=" in form partial as suggested by [RAJ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29579377/1047207) ]

The question model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :survey_questions
    has_many :surveys, :through => :survey_questions
end
```

The Survey model:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :survey_questions
    has_many :questions, :through => :survey_questions

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :survey_questions
end
```

The SurveyQuestion join table:

```
class SurveyQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :survey
    belongs_to :question
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :question
end
```

The /surveys/_form.html.erb partial:

```
<%= form_for @survey do |f|%>
    <h3>The Survey Itself</h3>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %> <br/>

    <h3>Questions:</h3>
    <%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
    <p>
        <%= builder.label :question_text, "Question Text" %><br />
        <%= builder.text_field :question_text %>
    </p>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

The /surveys/new.html.erb view:

```
<h1>New Survey</h1>
<%= render :partial => "form" %>
```

And, finally, the SurveysController:

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  # I have a few other actions here, like list, edit, delete and so forth

  def new
    @survey = Survey.new

    3.times do
        question = @survey.questions.build
        survey_question_combo = @survey.survey_questions.build
  end

  def create
    @survey = Survey.new(params[:survey].permit(:title))
    if @survey.save
        redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @survey
    else
        render :action => "new"
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that when I create a new Survey, the HTML displays up to the h3 "Questions", but nothing below that.  How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

In your `_form` partial, you need to add `=` before `f.fields_for` so that it shows on the page.

```
<%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
  <p>
    <%= builder.label :question_text, "Question Text" %><br />
    <%= builder.text_field :question_text %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Additionally, you can update your `new.html.erb` as:

```
<h1>New Survey</h1>
<%= render :partial => "form" %>
```

Comment: Thanks.  That did help display one Question text, but not the 10 as I wanted from the 10.times { ... }

Answer (score 0):

While I am still unsure of what the problem is above, I found a nice tutorial [here](https://hackhands.com/building-has_many-model-relationship-form-cocoon/).  It uses a gem called [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon).